# What is the pythonic way to add an array of dimensions (y,x) to the bottom an array of dimensions (3, y, x)?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

This is a method I am trying to apply to RGBA image arrays where, if the (1-D) 'extract_arr' has black text pixels (denoted by 4's), those pixels in the same location in 'sample' are made transparent (in 'a_layer_out' denoted by 1 for opaque and 0 for transparent). What's a more Pythonic way to do this? I've tried append, insert and vstack but they didn't like the dimension mis-match. Basically, I want to add an A layer to a 3-D (RGB) image array

```
sample = np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 6,4))
extract = [[0,4,0,0],[4,0,0,4],[4,4,4,0],[0,0,4,0],[0,0,4,0],[0,0,0,4]]
extract_arr = np.array(extract)
a_layer_out = np.full((6,4), 1)
sample_rgba1 = np.empty((4,6,4), dtype=int)

for i in range(sample.shape[0]): #dimension
    for j in range(sample.shape[1]): # row
        for k in range(sample.shape[2]): #column
            if extract_arr[j,k] ==4:
                a_layer_out[j,k] = 0 # I want zeros in every layer at that location if there is a 4 at that location in extract
            else:      
                pass

sample_rgba1[0] = sample[0]
sample_rgba1[1] = sample[1]
sample_rgba1[2] = sample[2]
sample_rgba1[3] = a_layer_out

sample_rgba1
```

Comment: You should be able to use `vstack`.

Comment: I tried this and got the dimension mismatch error:
`sample_out = np.vstack((sample, a_layer_out)) #sample is (3,6,4) a_layer is (6,4), desired result is (4,6,4)`
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: To join a (3,6,4) and a (6,4), the second has to be reshaped to (1,6,4).  Then you can `concatenate` on axis 0.  `vstack` does the axis 0 part, but only changes changes a 1d to 2d, so is not enough.  I'd suggest reading the docs for `concatenate` (and maybe the other 'stacks'), but also need to understand dimensions, including the difference between a (6,4) and (1,6,4).

Comment: @mkrieger1, your RGBA duplicate assumes the channel dimension is last (of 3).  Here it's first.  `vstack` can join 1 and 2 arrays, but doesn't make the necessary adjustments to join a 3d and 2d.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj. My fix was to make a_layer (1,6,4) to start with and keep it simple